# Passing 2D Array in JSON

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a 2 dimensional array that needs to be passed to the server side from front end using JSON. My JSON code looks something like this, where StoreHidden is the 2D array and consists of string:

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Home/DatatoInsert",
            data: JSON.stringify(StoreHidden),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            traditional: true
        })
```

The controller code is as follows:

```
public ActionResult DatatoInsert(String[][] arraydata)
    {
        UpdateForecast obj = new UpdateForecast();
        obj.UpdateDeliveryTable(arraydata);
        return this.Json(null);
    }
```

Data in the array to a certain amount is processed successfully. However, when a large amount of data is sent to the server end, an error is generated.

The web.config looks as follows:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483644"/>
<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
```

Please help.

Comment: What error is generated?

Comment: I get the error "An error occurred Error not found". I am unable to get the error at code level since the code works fine in my local machine.